# immutablejs mergeWith objects but overwrite new lists

Tags: immutable.js

I'm merging objects together, but one issue I'm having is that when I merge an object with a list, instead of using one of the other, it combines them. Is there anyway to get around this?

Ie.

```
obj1 = fromJS({name: 'kim', friends: [1,2,3]})
obj2 = fromJS({pet: 'Alex', friends: [4,5,6]})
obj1.mergeWith(obj2)
===> Desired Result
obj3 = fromJS({name: 'kim', pet: 'Alex', friends: [4,5,6]})
===> Actual Result
obj3 = fromJS({name: 'kim', pet: 'Alex', friends: [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

Comment: `mergeWith` is working as expected. Your desire is unconventional and probably easier done by manually changing the `friends` to `obj2.friends`.

Comment: I understand that's the default behaviour, but I need the functionality I described

Comment: In that case, simply update the friends list in the merged object with the preferred list using set.

Answer (score 3):

immutable gives you a mergeWith function which lets you define how to deal with conflicts.

```
export function mergeWithoutList(prev, next){
    if(typeof next == 'object'){
        if(List.isList(prev)){
            return next
        }else{
            return prev.mergeWith(mergeWithoutList, next)
        }
    }
    return next
}

    obj3 = obj1.mergeWith(mergeWithoutList, obj2)
=>
obj3 == fromJS({name: 'kim', pet: 'Alex', friends: [4,5,6]})
```